# ¿Como cargar mi DatePickerDialog en formato de 24 horas Android?

Tags: android, datetime

Como puede mejorar el siguiente código que compartiré para que al hacer clic en un botón cargue el DatePickerDialog en formato 24 horas si o si, ya que por el momento me carga en el formato que el usuario tiene configurado en su sistema ya sea 12 horas o 24 horas.

> Aca les comparto el código

```
public void obtenerHora(){

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    final int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    final int am_pm = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);


    TimePickerDialog recogerHora = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            //mEtHora: es un edit text que almacenara la hora seleccionada por el usuario
        mEtHora.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

        }
    }, hour, minute, false);


    recogerHora.show();

}
```

> En algunas ayudas he visto que utilizan **setIs24HourView(true)**, pero siempre y cuando sea un **TimePicker** embebido en el layout.

Comment: Ahora noto la observacion final en tu pregunta. Te lanza algún error cuando el metodo que escribes eso?

Comment: setIs24HourView(true), simplemente no reconoce al método sale de color rojo.

Comment: Mira mi respuesta actualizada y despues cuentame como te fue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza el metodo [`setIs24HourView(boolean)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView%28java.lang.Boolean%29) pasandole `true` y forzara a 24 horas :

```
recogerHora.setIs24HourView(true);
recogerHora.show();
```

---

Como utilizas [`TimePickerDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html), en el constructor se lo puedes especificar que utilize el formato de 24 horas:

```
new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int i, int i1) {

            }
        }, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE), true);
```

Fijate que el ultimo parametro es donde le indicas si utilizar el formato 24 horas.

Entonces en tu caso solo cambiale el ultimo parametro a true:

```
public void obtenerHora(){

final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
final int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
final int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
final int am_pm = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);

// que utilize formato de 24 horas
boolean formato24Horas = true;

TimePickerDialog recogerHora = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        //mEtHora: es un edit text que almacenara la hora seleccionada por el usuario
    mEtHora.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

    }
}, hour, minute, formato24Horas );


recogerHora.show();

}
```

Comment: recogerHora.setIs24HourView(true), el método no es reconocido.

Comment: Entonces como quedaría, una vez modificado el código anterior.

Comment: En el codigo que publicaste, cambia el ultimo parametro a `true`

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Funciona perfecto, excelente amigo.